# Matlab: Convolving or Correlating one vector with many other vectors

Tags: matlab, correlation, convolution

I have vector y, and vectors x1,x2,...,x50. I need to correlate or convolve y with each of the x vectors. I'm currently doing this in a FOR loop, but it is slow and I'm trying to find a way to do them at once. [This help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/correlation-and-covariance.html#f12-6580) has a section on correlation with multiple channels (which seems like what I need to do), but only talks about autocorrelation. I have tried using the xcorr function with a vector and a matrix (the matrix being the x vectors side by side), but that doesn't work. Any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try something like `y_expanded = repmat(y, 1, 50); xc = xcorr(x, y_expanded)` (in fact, I think `bsxfun(@xcorr, x, y)` might do the trick as well). Not sure it'd be any faster though, as ultimately it still has to loop to do the calculation for each pair of vectors...

Comment: @wakjah When I try xcorr(x,y_expanded), I get a "B must be a vector" error. It seems that this function can't actually accept matrices as arguments. bsxfun gives an "invalid output dimensions" error, I'm not sure if xcorr is a valid function to use there.

Comment: @Jordan How many vectors do you have? You could try padding one of the vectors to the matrix and then calling `FFT2` to do the convolution. It's a waste of memory but it should be decently fast.

Comment: @jucestain I have 128 vectors.

Comment: @Jordan What are the length of these vectors? Also, if you implement the convolutions yourself with FFTs you only have to take the FFT of the single vector that you are convolving with others once. This will probably cut some time off. I profiled the `fft2` vs a for loop with `fft` and sometimes a single `fft2` is faster and sometimes it's not so I'd just disregard my first comment.

Comment: @jucestain y is 88 samples, each x is about 8000 samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT USE, SLOW!**

If your vectors are stored in a cell array, you can use `cellfun`:

```
y = [ ... ];
xs = { [ ... ], [ ... ], [ ... ] };

res = cellfun(@(x) xcorr(x,y), xs, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

`res` is now a cell array with the correlations.

<del>This should be faster than a for loop (untested), as the loop does not have to be interpreted.</del>

You can convert a matrix to a cell array of vectors using `mat2cell`.

**UPDATE**

Tested with:

```
xm = rand(n);
xc = mat2cell(xm, ones(n,1), n);
y  = rand([n 1]);

tic
for i = 1:n
   xcorr(y,xm(i,:)); 
end
toc

tic
cellfun(@(x) xcorr(x,y), xc, 'UniformOutput', false);
toc
```

For `n = 5000`

```
Elapsed time is 5.713080 seconds.
Elapsed time is 7.003739 seconds.
```

For `n = 10000`

```
Elapsed time is 15.283524 seconds.
Elapsed time is 18.009520 seconds.
```

So it is indeed even slower.

Comment: I am almost certain this will be very slow. `cellfun` is only faster than a forloop implementation when using one of the built in functions if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunately true. I am testing this right now. Post results in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a matrix X of size [1000, 50] we wish to convolve with a vector v of size [50]. Now instead of the slow:

```
 Y=zeros(size(X))
 for i=1:1000
      Y(i,:)=conv(X,v,'same')
 end
```

One may do:

```
 V=convmtx(v, 50);
 Y=X*V
 Y=Y(:,1:50)
```

And remove the last line if you're interested in 'full' convolution rather than 'same'.